# Can't get checkboxes to work

Tags: google-maps-api-3, checkbox, filter, markers

I've been reading through various posts and have been trying to get the check boxes to control my markers (on/off), to no avail. The code below is what i've managed thus far, but unfortunately it still does not work.

Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated.

Have got it working with `xml` but I want to use `js/json` files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
var json = [{
        "Name" : "NER 1",
        "Latitude" : 51.50732,
        "Longitude" : -0.128673,
        "Connect" : "BS123",
        "ChargeR" : "Standard",
        "ConType" : 1,
        "Operator" : "NER",
    },{
        "Name" : "NER 2",
        "Latitude" : 51.506906,
        "Longitude" : -0.126548,
        "Connect" : "BS234",
        "ChargeR" : "Standard",
        "ConType" : 2,
        "Operator" : "NER",
    },{
        "Name" : "SEW 3",
        "Latitude" : 51.508382,
        "Longitude" : -0.129724,
        "Connect" : "BS345",
        "ChargeR" : "Standard",
        "ConType" : 3,
        "Operator" : "SEW",
    },{
        "Name" : "SEW 1",
        "Latitude" : 51.508322,
        "Longitude" : -0.126902,
        "Connect" : "BS123",
        "ChargeR" : "Standard",
        "ConType" : 4,
        "Operator" : "SEW",
    },{
        "Name" : "TAW 2",
        "Latitude" : 51.507841,
        "Longitude" : -0.126066,
        "Connect" : "BS234",
        "ChargeR" : "Standard",
        "ConType" : 2,
        "Operator" : "TAW",
    },{
        "Name" : "TAW 3",
        "Latitude" : 51.50746,
        "Longitude" : -0.12759,
        "Connect" : "BS345",
        "ChargeR" : "Standard",
        "ConType" : 3,
        "Operator" : "TAW",
    },{
        "Name" : "RCR 1",
        "Latitude" : 51.506439,
        "Longitude" : -0.127922,
        "Connect" : "BS234",
        "ChargeR" : "Standard",
        "ConType" : 4,
        "Operator" : "NER",
    },{
        "Name" : "RCR 2",
        "Latitude" : 51.50943,
        "Longitude" : -0.127428,
        "Connect" : "BS234",
        "ChargeR" : "Standard",
        "ConType" : 2,
        "Operator" : "NER",
    }
]
// JavaScript Document
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508075,-0.127873);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: true,
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);    


        var markers = [];
        var categoryIcons = {}
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
          var data = json[i],
            latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map : map,
            title : data.Name,
            icon : categoryIcons[data.ConType],
          });    
          // === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
          marker.mycategory = data.ConType;
          marker.myname = data.Name;
          marker.myoperator = data.Operator,              
           markers.push(marker);
           // end Looping through the JSON data
           <!-- Map traffic begin -->       
          (function (marker, data) {
                // Attaching a click event to the current marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {}); // end Attaching a click event to the current marker    
            })(marker, data); // end Creating a closure 

            // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
      function show(category) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
          }
        }
        // == check the checkbox ==
        document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
      }

      // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
      function hide(category) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
          }
        }
        // == clear the checkbox ==
        document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
        // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
        infoBubble.close();
      }

      // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
      function boxclick(box,category) {
        if (box.checked) {
          show(category);
        } else {
          hide(category);
        }
        // == rebuild the side bar
        makeSidebar();
      }

      function myclick(i) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
      } 

        }   
        }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="initialize()">
<div id="map" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 1000px; height: 650px;"></div>
<div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 1000px; height: 650px;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" class="cas" name="1" value="1" onclick="boxclick(this,'1')" checked/>1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2" class="cas" name="2" value="2" onclick="boxclick(this,'2')" checked/>2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="3" class="cas" name="3" value="3" onclick="boxclick(this,'3')" checked/>3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="4" class="cas" name="4" value="4" onclick="boxclick(this,'4')" checked/>4
    </div>
```

Cheers

Comment: The checkbox functionality should be the same as the "working" XML version (assuming the information in the JSON is the same as that in the XML).  What does the XML code look like?  Do you have a live version or a jsfiddle (so you don't have to clutter up this question)?

Answer (score 0):

All your functions are local to the initialize function.  To be used from HTML click events, they need to be in the global scope.  The gmarkers array is undefined.

```
var gmarkers = [];
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.508075,-0.127873);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: true,
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);


    var categoryIcons = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      var data = json[i],
      latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map : map,
            title : data.Name,
            icon : categoryIcons[data.ConType],
      });
      // === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
      marker.mycategory = data.ConType;
      marker.myname = data.Name;
      marker.myoperator = data.Operator,
      gmarkers.push(marker);
      // end Looping through the JSON data
      <!-- Map traffic begin -->
      (function (marker, data) {
          // Attaching a click event to the current marker
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {}); // end Attaching a click event to the current marker
          })(marker, data); // end Creating a closure

      }
} // end of initialize function

// == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
function show(category) {
  for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
    if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
      gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
    }
  }
  // == check the checkbox ==
  document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
}

// == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
function hide(category) {
  for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
    if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
      gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
    }
  }
  // == clear the checkbox ==
  document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
  // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
  infoBubble.close();
}

// == a checkbox has been clicked ==
function boxclick(box,category) {
  if (box.checked) {
    show(category);
  } else {
    hide(category);
  }
  // == rebuild the side bar
  makeSidebar();
}

function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```